# Divs in a responsive grid-style layout with no vertical gap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have a collection of `div`s (cards).  Each one will have a title, description, and image (all of varying lengths / sizes).

I want to display these "nicely" on screen.

By "nicely" I mean I want the image to be a thumbnail - horizontally centered after the title and description.

More importantly I want the card (containing `div`) to be positioned one after the other (horizontally then vertically) and without any large vertical gaps.

Example:

[image: cards-layout]

I'm using Bootstrap's responsive column classes (`col-lg`, `col-md`, `col-sm`) and `img-responsive`.  The main problem I'm hitting is the large vertical gaps.

Here's an [attempt](http://codepen.io/poakey1/pen/dXyMJb?editors=1100) of mine.

Any CSS tricks to achieve a layout similar to my image above?  (Only with fewer columns on smaller displays).

Comment: You can google "waterfall js", then you can get what you want

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve this layout is using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

STEP by STEP:

1. you start by adding this:

   ```
   <script src="/path/to/masonry.pkgd.min.js">`</script>
   ```

   or using **CDN**

   ```
   <script src="https://npmcdn.com/masonry-layout@4.0/dist/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
   <!-- or -->
   <script src="https://npmcdn.com/masonry-layout@4.0/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. then this would be your HTML markup

   ```
   <div class="grid">
     <div class="grid-item">...</div>
     <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2">...</div>
     <div class="grid-item">...</div>
     ...
   </div>
   ```
3. And this CSS

   ```css
   .grid-item { width: 200px; }
   .grid-item--width2 { width: 400px; }
   ```
4. If you are using jQuery library , you can use it as a plugin and initialize it like this:

   ```
   $('.grid').masonry({
     // options
     itemSelector: '.grid-item',
     columnWidth: 200
   });
   ```
5. otherwise you can initialize with vanilla JS like this:

   ```
   var elem = document.querySelector('.grid');
   var msnry = new Masonry( elem, {
     // options
     itemSelector: '.grid-item',
     columnWidth: 200
   });    
   // element argument can be a selector string
   //   for an individual element
   var msnry = new Masonry( '.grid', {
     // options
   });
   ```

PS- You can also initialize in HTML without any JS.

For further instructions, see Get Started [here](http://masonry.desandro.com/#getting-started)

---

Using CSS only, you can either use CSS Columns or CSS Flexbox. but  it will lose in cross browser compatibility to the Masonry plugin

Comment: Thanks - that looks like the kind of thing I'm after - although the clearfix doesn't seem to work with my implementation... nor on the examples (unless I'm doing it wrong).  http://codepen.io/poakey1/pen/dXyMJb

Comment: masonry doesn't use `clearfix`, if this helps your issue make sure you mark the answer as accepted

Comment: I need to be able to encapsulate the images in the parent div completely, i.e. clearfix.

Comment: @PeteGO see if this help you out https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-masonry-layout/

Comment: This answer doesn't provide a CSS solution as asked for, nor does it elaborate on why it's not possible with CSS only - it simply shoves a framework in the reader's face, along with a questionable statement of the "best" solution. I can't believe I'm linking this to someone with 23k+ reputation, but here's [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm really not going to argue with you on this. I told the OP what was the best option given OP requirements and to **NOT HAVE A LINK ONLY ANSWER** I described, explaining how the method works, so yes this is a good answer. Thank you very much. By the way Thanks for the downvote ;)

Comment: I'm not trying to argue, but giving feedback on the downvote, which I feel is justified because you're making the assumption that using a JS library is acceptable, even though the question states they're looking for a CSS solution. It may not be a link-only answer, but as far as understanding the technical side goes, it doesn't help. You described how to implement Masonry, but not why a CSS-only solution isn't feasible, or any other justification to use another library at all.